# Hide rows with criteria on click

Tags: google-apps-script

I already have simple google spreadsheets script which is hiding columns and rows when i select different values in trigger cell.

```
function hideColumns() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.hideColumns(2, 3); // B-D, three columns starting from 2nd   
    sheet.hideColumn(7);     // G, column 7
}

function showColumns() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.showColumns(2, 3); // B-D, three columns starting from 2nd    
    sheet.showColumn(7);     //  G, column number 7 
}

function onEdit(e) {

    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'B2' || sheet.getName() !== 'sheet1') 
        return;
    switch (e.value) {
        case '01':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)
            sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1)
            break;
        case '02':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)
            sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1)
            sheet.hideColumns(6, 4)
            sheet.hideRows(12, 1)
            break;
        case '03':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)
            sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1)
            sheet.hideColumns(4, 2)
            sheet.hideColumns(8, 2)
            sheet.hideRows(12, 1)
            sheet.hideRows(7, 3)
            break;
        case '04':
            sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns() - 1)
            sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1)
            sheet.hideColumns(4, 4)
            sheet.hideRows(12, 1)
            break;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to add ability to hide not only exact rows but also rows in four different ranges (like 20-40, 30-35, 50-60 etc) that matches the criteria: if "C" cell in this row is blank or equal 0.

I tried search but have no idea how to implement codes I found to my one.

Could you please help?

Comment: For now I have all rows needed to be hide colored in one specific colour. I made it with conditional formatting. So basically now I could just hide all rows with this colour.

Comment: Rodion Zhabrev you don't follow the rules of the community

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться в сообщество на русском языке https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/103356854721490738172

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Your approach is not comprehensive. I think.

Let imagine we have a filter function which returns true when it's all right.

```
/*
 * v is value of a cell
 * i is current row - 1
 * j is current column -1
 */
function filter(v, i, j) {
    return v !== '#ff0000' && j == 2;
}
```

Also we have a rows hider. Like this

```
/*
 * blocks is 2D array. It contains pairs of rows indexes and counts rows for hiding.
 * [[1, 2],[5, 4]] This hides from first row two items, from fifth row four items.
 */
function hiderRows(sheet, blocks) {
    for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        sheet.hideRows(blocks[i][0], blocks[i][1]);
    }
    return sheet;
}
```

We need a blocks builder. Let's do it!

```
function blockBilder(sheet, callback, colors) {
    var cmd = colors ? 'getBackgrounds' : 'getValues';
    var values = sheet.getDataRange()[cmd]();
    var blocks = [];
    var delta = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if (callback(values[i][j], i, j)) {
                if (delta === i - 1) {
                    blocks[blocks.length - 1][1]++;
                } else {
                    blocks.push([i + 1, 1]);
                }
                delta = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return blocks;
}
```

Run it!

```
function test() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
    var blocks = blockBilder(sheet, filter, 'any value here');
    hiderRows(sheet, blocks);
}
```

- You could get the full working code from https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/030787ea594e4116e72991e34fcd079a
- You could notice that the `blockBilder` can works with backgrounds color or values.